# How search key is searched in the "index file"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

What I have understood till now is that in database data is actually stored on hard disk in blocks in files, and an index points to the block of the file where data is actually stored.

Now, what I am wondering is that how a search key is searched in the index files, suppose my query is `select empname from employee where empid = 12345` and I have index on `empid` then what I think is that "**index file**" will contain all the employee id's. and then how empid 12345 will be searched in that, sequentially?

Comment: On the Oracle side, it would be a bit more accurate to say that the table data and index data are stored in blocks, which are all stored in segments, which are stored in tablespaces, which are stored in datafiles, which are stored on disk.

Answer (score 0):

> an index points to the block of the file where data is actually
>   stored.

A **non-clustered** index points to where the data is actually stored

There are two types of index:

- A clustered index - where the rows are physically stored in the disk
  in the order specified in the index.
- A non clustered index - a reference to a data page where the data
  is stored.

A table can only have one clustered index (as the data can only be physically stored one way) but can have many non-clustered indexes.

The process of finding the data using the index you have described is called an index seek

Consider the diagram below which is similar to your example

[image]

The index seek will start at the root node (Level 2 on the diagram) To find your example of 12345 we have to go down to level 1 via the left branch of the tree because the value we are looking for falls into that value range.

We then have multiple leaf nodes to find our value on level 0 (the diagram shows three for simplicity but there could be hundreds) each leaf node in the diagram holds 2000 values so we then go to the one which holds 12345. We then search each value in that range and check if it is 12345.

Once we have our value, what happens next depends on whether the index is a clustered or non-clustered index, if it is a clustered index, we retrieve the value, if it is a non clustered index, we go to the datapage it refers to and then retrieve the value.

[Example diagram taken from here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/)